# Cannot get property 'packageName' on null object

Tags: react-native

I just run below steps
1. git clone https://mycaccount@bitbucket.org/somename/appname.git
2.git checkout developer
3.git pull origin
4.get checkout mynewbrange
5. react-native run-android

This project is working in other 4 developers pc and they are using mac 

I am using in windows 8 but when i run run-android commant it is not working
and i don't share any code because i guss this is some confoguration issue any one please help to solve this issue 
if you need to view code then ask me i will update .the reasion why i am not updateing code now is i think the issue is not related to code

PS F:\reactnative2\appname\appbuyer> react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'F:\reactnative2\appname\appbuyer\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 196
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'appbuyer'.

  > Cannot get property 'packageName' on null object
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'F:\reactnative2\appname\appbuyer\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 196
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'appbuyer'.

  > Cannot get property 'packageName' on null object
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (F:\reactnative2\appname\appbuyer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.jbuild\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (F:\reactnative2\appname\appbuyer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)d\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)                                                                                 d\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12)
at then.result (F:\reactnative2\appname\appbuyer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

```
react-native run-android  --stacktrace
error: unknown option `--stacktrace'
```

Comment: Did you do npm install?

Answer (score -1):

Check with node modules are installed and android folder.To install the node modules run **npm install**.Need android sdk to work with android.please check have you installed all the required dependencies.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started